# How to check if a word entered in a textbox is spelled correctly?

Tags: php

I have a textbox `input type="text" maxlength="30"`.

A user is allowed to enter one word only in this textbox. How can I force the user to enter the right spelling?

It should show a message stating "wrong spelling" when a user enters the wrong spelling... Otherwise, the user can go ahead and submit... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you comparing the word to a captcha or could the word be ANY word but spelled correctly.

Answer (score 3):

There are various third party components for spell check suport:

- PHP Spell Check: http://phpspellcheck.com/ ($99 for one web site)
- Spell check via Yahoo API: http://phpcollection.com/spell-check-php-yahoo-api/ (requires Yahoo App ID)

You can also look into the built-in support (PHP 5.3+) for the [Enchant](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) library, although this still requires a spell-checking backend like [Aspell](http://aspell.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www.1001line.net/spell-check/) out. It will let you add the spell check to your textbox in a few easy steps.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, and there is only going to be one possible word that you are looking for, then just check if the entered value is equal to that (e.g. `if(inputValue == 'Word')`)

Comment: Why the downvote? In the question, it is stated that the user will enter "only one word". If that is taken to mean one specific word, what is wrong with the approach in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a Spell Check As You Type Plugin..

Check out :

http://www.spellchecker.net/v3/products/scayt.html

and

http://www.jspell.com/ajax-spell-checker-as-you-type.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from your post you are trying to catch the input value matching *before* the form is submitted.

> What i want is it should show a
>   message wrong spelling when user
>   enters wrong spelling... **Otherwise
>   user can go ahead and submit**...

If so, this sounds like a job for javascript/AJAX.  You have the script check against a value that could be stored server side (for security?) on either on a key press up or blur event handler.  This script could also handle displaying messages back to the user as well, based on the return value of the AJAX call or whatnot.  This could also be used to enable/disable the submit button too.